# Visual Studio Cmake generated project rebuilds all time even if the build is successful

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

In Visual Studio, my Cmake generated project rebuilds all the time, even if build is successful.

Each time I got something like this:

```
1>------ Up-To-Date check: Project: project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Project is not up-to-date: build input 'c:\project\cmakelists.txt' is missing.
1>------ Build started: Project: project, Configuration: Debug Win32 -----
```

Comment: It is very difficult to find a problem in the code, which we don't see... (Add the code into the question post. It is a [rule of the Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Comment: ok, i.ll create simple example

Comment: "'c:\project\cmakelists.txt' is missing" is not clear enough?